# Flex RSL Vs Modules

Tags: apache-flex, module, rsl

I am in the confusion advantages or uses of RSL and Modules.
It is said that RSLs will be cached in the browser, so that they can be used across multiple applications without loading the same library again.
My question is,
Since the Modules also published as swf only and Willthey also will get cached as like any other application (swf) ?
What is the special logic used in the RSL will get cache?
How does the cache logic differs for RSL than Modules?

thanks,
Mani

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of RSL's: signed (by Adobe) and unsigned (like you and I would make)

The signed RSL's contain the Flex framework classes, and are actually cached by the Flash Player itself. You can reduce the size of your application by using these RSL's (the default in Flex 4).

You can compile your own code into unsigned RSL's or Flex Modules. Both of these are cached by the browser, as usual.

Module SWF's can be loaded by an application at anytime, RSL's are loaded up front at application startup.

Theres a definite advantage to using the Flex framework RSL's, but for your own code Modules might have an advantage b/c they don't force the code to be loaded at app startup time.